# Почему Entity - это POJO-класс?

Tags: java, java-8, entity, pojo

На википедии черном по белому написано:

> Entity (Сущность) — POJO-класс, связанный с БД с помощью аннотации (@Entity) или через XML.

Однако просматривая особенности POJO-класса, я узнал, что он не должен:

- Расширять заранее заданные классы.
- Реализовывать заранее заданные интерфейсы.
- Содержать предварительно определенные аннотации.

Однако, на той же википедии написано, что Entity-класс может и наследоваться, и интерфейсы реализовывать, и аннотации использовать. Так вот, означает ли это, что Entity-класс должен быть POJO именно до его превращения в Entity? Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этих определениях важно слово *заранее заданные*. В библиотеке Entity Java Beans сущности наследовались от класса `EJBObject`, что накладывало серьёзные ограничения на разработку.

Например, вы не могли просто взять готовую библиотеку классов, и подключить её к проекту. Чтобы сделать свои классы сущностями в смысле Entity Java Beans, вы должно были их переписать. Сами классы становились большими, потому что помимо своей основной задачи они переопределяли «нужные» методы из `EJBObject`.

POJO означает, что вы не должны наследоваться ни от какого специального базового класса наподобие `EJBObject`. Но конечно вы можете наследовать POJO-классы друг от друга так, как это диктует логика предметной области.